# Installed 11.10, but it's not detecting all 8GB of RAM, only 3.9GB.  BIOS sees 8GB

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, ram

Just installed 11.10, but it's not detecting all 8GB of RAM. System Info says there are 3.9GB. Bios doesn't have a problem recognizing all 8.

```
free -m
```

results in:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3957       1478       2479          0         22        687
-/+ buffers/cache:        768       3189
Swap:         4089          0       4089
```

Comment: can you post the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` ?

Comment: First, are you really on 64-bit? `uname -a`

Comment: you probably got 32bit, not 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

3.9 GB is the limit for 32-bit, you probably installed the wrong version. If you are indeed running 64-bit, the `uname -m` command should output x86_64.

Comment: this is not true, practically every recent release of Ubuntu uses the PAE module for the kernel when a 32 bit is used on a machine with more than 3.5Gb of RAM, so this is not a valid explanation

Comment: The PAE kernel is not automatically installed, @Micro.  In most Ubuntu Desktop situations, its not installed by default.  The last release that I saw which by default installed the PAE kernel over the non-PAE kernel was 10.04.0 LTS.  Every release since, I have yet to see it auto-install the PAE kernel.  So Dalton's statements are somewhat correct to that extent.

Comment: in my experience the PAE module is always present, i never ever experienced a 32 bit installation without the PAE module, at least this is true for me since lucid.

Comment: @Micro: and yet he is right, 4 GiB *is* the limit for 32bit. PAE actually adds bits internally, thus his assertion is right, albeit somewhat incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy this to the terminal, and hit enter, to write your password:
`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae` and after reboot, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The PAE kernel is not installed by default. You need to install the following packages:

```
linux-image-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae
```

using

```
apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae
```

The headers are only relevant if you need to build code on the machine. If you are using a package such as `build-essential` this should be pulled automagically.

Hopefully this helps...

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Comment: Ok. Feel free to edit or suggest edits, sorry